# Problem running a python script that imports glob package to scan through a directory of PDFs

Tags: python, parsing, glob

I am trying to run a program that should scan through all pdf files in "New Folder" directory, extract relevant string values and produce a table, in a new computer.

The code is as below

```
    def check_rate(rating):
    Rating=rating.upper()
    U="Unsafe"
    NR="Needs Rectification"
    II="Improvements identified"
    A="Adequate"
    if Rating[:2]=="1H":
        return U
    elif Rating[:2]=="2H":
        return NR
    elif Rating[:2]=="2M":
        return II
    elif Rating[:2]=="2L":
        return A
    elif Rating[:2]=="3L":
        return A
    elif "UNSAFE" in Rating:
        return U
    elif "NEEDS RECTIFICATION" in Rating:
        return NR
    elif "IMPROVEMENTS IDENTIFIED" in Rating:
        return II
    elif "ADEQUATE" in Rating:
        return A


import glob
import pandas as pd
files=glob.glob("./New folder/*.pdf")
df_name=pd.DataFrame(files,columns=['FileName'])
x=0
y=len(df_name)
df_name["SV_ID"]=""
while x < y:
    i1=df_name["FileName"][x][22]
    i2=df_name["FileName"][x][23]
    i3=df_name["FileName"][x][24]
    if i1==" " or i1=="-" or i1==".":
        df_name.at[x,"SV_ID"]=df_name["FileName"][x][13:22]
    elif i2==" " or i2=="-" or i2==".":
        df_name.at[x,"SV_ID"]=df_name["FileName"][x][13:23]
    elif i3==" " or i3=="-" or i3==".":
        df_name.at[x,"SV_ID"]=df_name["FileName"][x][13:24]
    else:
        df_name.at[x,"SV_ID"]="N/A"
    x+=1
df_name.to_csv('name2.csv')
df_ref=pd.read_csv('CheckListItems.csv')
df_Rate=pd.read_csv('TechSafe.csv')

from tika import parser

line=0
n1=0
while n1<y:
    rawText = parser.from_file(df_name['FileName'][n1])

    rawList = rawText['content'].splitlines()

    n=0
    long=len(rawList)
    version=''
    while n<long:
        word=rawList[n].strip().upper()
        if word[:27]=='SOLAR VICTORIA AUDIT REPORT':
            version=word[43:]
        if word[-1:]==".":
            word=word[:-1]
        if word in list(df_ref["Reference"]):
            add=1
            while add<45 and n+add<long:
                wordcheck=rawList[n+add].strip()
                
                if wordcheck[-1:]==".":
                    wordcheck=wordcheck[:-1]
                if wordcheck in list(df_ref["Reference"]):
                    add=45

                if wordcheck[:8] == "Rating -":
                    df_Rate.at[line,'SV_ID']=df_name['SV_ID'][n1]
                    df_Rate.at[line,'Ref']=word
                    df_Rate.at[line,'Rate']=check_rate(rawList[n+add+1].strip())
                    df_Rate.at[line,'Version']=version
                    add=45
                    line+=1
#                    print(df_name['SV_ID'][n1],wordcheck)

                    
                elif wordcheck[:7] == "Rating ":
                    df_Rate.at[line,'SV_ID']=df_name['SV_ID'][n1]
                    df_Rate.at[line,'Ref']=word
                    wordcheck=wordcheck[7:]
                    df_Rate.at[line,'Rate']=check_rate(wordcheck)
                    df_Rate.at[line,'Version']=version
                    add=45
                    line+=1
#                    print(df_name['SV_ID'][n1],wordcheck)
                    
                
# Old process




                        
                    line+=1

                add+=1

        n+=1
    n1+=1
    print(n1*100//y,"%")
df_Rate.to_csv('1.1 Finding Draft.csv')
df_Rate.tail()
```

This should produce a table as below

| SV_ID | Ref | Rate | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INS00102811 | PCE 23 | Improvements identified | V2.4C |

I do not think the issue lies in the pdfs or in the main body of the script. I think the issue lies mostly with the packages. This code works fine in my friends computer, wh ran it real time in front of me, but it does not work in mine. We might have different versions of python and we are running on jupyter notebook.

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8f6d401ba180> in <module>
     46     x+=1
     47 df_name.to_csv('name2.csv')
---> 48 df_ref=pd.read_csv('CheckListItems.csv')
     49 df_Rate=pd.read_csv('TechSafe.csv')
     50 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    684     )
    685 
--> 686     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    687 
    688 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    450 
    451     # Create the parser.
--> 452     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    453 
    454     if chunksize or iterator:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    944             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    945 
--> 946         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    947 
    948     def close(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1176     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):
   1177         if engine == "c":
-> 1178             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1179         else:
   1180             if engine == "python":

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   2006         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   2007 
-> 2008         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   2009         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   2010 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'CheckListItems.csv'
```

I created an empty file named " CheckListItels.csv".

Now I its showing the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8f6d401ba180> in <module>
     49 df_Rate=pd.read_csv('TechSafe.csv')
     50 
---> 51 from tika import parser
     52 
     53 line=0

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tika'
```

Assuming its a package installation issue, i tried installing glob

```
(base) C:\>pip install glob2
Requirement already satisfied: glob2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.7)
```

I am using Python version 3.8.5.

I am not sure how can I make this code run. Please help. Thank you.

Thank you for your kind suggestions.
As per advise I installed tika from anacondas gui.
The error I find is as follows:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Reference'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8f6d401ba180> in <module>
     67         if word[-1:]==".":
     68             word=word[:-1]
---> 69         if word in list(df_ref["Reference"]):
     70             add=1
     71             while add<45 and n+add<long:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Reference'
```

Comment: K J, That is a good advise. Thank you. I will do that. he is supposed to share all documents with me, he missed out probably.

Comment: Thank you. Apparently, some files were missing and was not shared with me earlier. Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is 99% likely to be the case that you're getting this error because the file is not where your code says it is - sorry!

The line:

```
df_ref=pd.read_csv('CheckListItems.csv')
```

is a relative path to the CheckListItems.csv file. So here is how I would troubleshoot it:

1. Make sure CheckListItems.csv is in the same directory as your jupyter notebook file. If it isn't, move it there.
2. In the unlikely event that doesn't fix it, provide an absolute path to CheckListItems.csv, i.e.

```
df_ref=pd.read_csv('/home/drislam/documents/python/CheckListItems.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my original question.

Answer (score 1):

The error states `CheckListItems.csv` cannot be found:

```
FileNotFoundError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8f6d401ba180> in <module>
     46     x+=1
     47 df_name.to_csv('name2.csv')
---> 48 df_ref=pd.read_csv('CheckListItems.csv')
```

Does the file `CheckListItems.csv` exist? Try creating an empty text file with that name and running again.

Comment: Thank you. I have created an empty list titled "CheckListItems.csv". I am having a different problem now. I have updated the original question.

Comment: You need to install tika based on the error you put in the question - that's what this error means ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tika'. Should be conda install tika or you can do it in the anaconda gui.

Comment: Thank you osnit_alex. I have updated the question above. Issue still persists.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone. Your comments helped me to understand the issue and guided me towards the right direction. Thank you again.